# how to open custom form in popup onclick in menu link drupal

Tags: 7

I made a custom form in drupal. I just want to open that form on popup form when user click on menu.

Here is my code

```
function acoma_extra_divide_element_horizontaly($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['description'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item',
    '#title' => t('At which height should the element be divided? (distance
    from cupboard floor)'),
  );

  $form['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Divide draw up horizontally'),
    '#suffix' => 'cm',
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'OK',
  );

  return $form;
}
```

Menu code is:

```
<div id="step3-menu" class="step3-menu" style="display:none;position: absolute">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Divide element horizontally</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="popup">Divide element vertically</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="popup">Reset element</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I just want when use click on menu this form loads in popup. I used the popup module.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. 
You can use  [Popup forms](https://drupal.org/project/popup_forms%20m) module. Its configuration is in documentation of module 
or [Modal Frame API](https://drupal.org/project/modalframe) module.